# How can I connect with api when my xmlhttprequest is blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, api, cors, xmlhttprequest, blocked

I am using XMLHttpRequest() to connect with API and in console I have error about blocked by CORS policy. My url use https. How to connect with that API? I need some API-KEY or something like that?

I installed Allow-Control-Allow-Origin extension to chrome. It doesn't help

Example:

```
  function UserAction() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 // xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.high;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://sinsmbe1.insepa.net:20106/m3api-rest/execute/CRS610MI/LstByNumber;maxrecs=100;returncols=CUNO,STAT?CUNO=10000", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

I have 3 information from console.

Warning:

> The connection used to load resources from
>   https://sinsmbe1.insepa.net:20106 used TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1, which are
>   deprecated and will be disabled in the future. Once disabled, users
>   will be prevented from loading these resources. The server should
>   enable TLS 1.2 or later. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5654791610957824 for more
>   information.

Error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://sinsmbe1.insepa.net:20106/m3api-rest/execute/CRS610MI/LstByNumber;maxrecs=100;returncols=CUNO,STAT?CUNO=10000'
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Warning:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://sinsmbe1.insepa.net:20106/m3api-rest/execute/CRS610MI/LstByNumber;maxrecs=100;returncols=CUNO,STAT?CUNO=10000
>   with MIME type application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

Comment: For debugging use this in firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/

Recently in chrome updated its security extension doesn't work any more

Comment: You already asked this yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56165837/how-make-connection-with-api-avoid-cors-in-this-code

Comment: "How to connect with that API? I need some API-KEY or something like that?" – You can't send an API key unless they give you permission to make the request. So no (or at least not yet).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these headers at your start of the api :

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept");
```

Comment: `var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept");` Something like above?

Comment: where did you executing the code?

Comment: @omlette — No. The API has to add the headers in the response. You can't give your own code permission to access arbitrary websites using your visitor's browsers.